# Strange Unity3D artifacts in scene and editor + crash

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, gpu, nvidia, artifact

since today black flickering artifacts are showing in my Unity scene, game and editor. In fact also letters from console, inspector and other windows seem to be corrupted. I also sometimes get a crash with the error below but no solution I found online solved this. I tried different unity versions, different projects, updating nvidia (geoforce 940mx) driver and disablind windows firewall. Thanks a lot if you can help me.

[Bug in text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBoEb.png)

[Bug in scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRNso.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaipj.png)

Answer (score 0):

from the error, looks like windows disabled your nvidia drivers. check if they're enabled or disabled by right clicking on your start menu, clicking device manager, finding your GPU, and clicking on the drivers tab in properties. if it is enabled, try to roll back drivers if the option is available, if not then try to go to the unity forums/ask site specifically, cause they might have an answer. Good luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).